# Create a scalable table with a cell with overflow:auto

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow

I have a table displaying tabular data in a scalable layout. The table itself has a width:100%.

In one of the columns, user data on rare occasion will include long strings that stretch the table outside of its container.

My solution was to put the contents of that cell inside a div, and give the div a `max-width:320px` and an overflow:auto.  This work in IE9 and FF7, the two browsers I'm concerned about.

```
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="max-width:320px; overflow:auto;">
        ReallyLongUnbrokenStringOfCharactersThatStretchesTheTableBeyondItsContainerReallyLongUnbrokenStringOfCharactersThatStretchesTheTableBeyondItsContainerReallyLongUnbrokenStringOfCharactersThatStretchesTheTableBeyondItsContainer
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, my preference is not to limit the column's contents to a max-width of 320px. I'd rather that the div stretches as needed with the table, and only overflows when the table no longer fits the screen.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

What i have done for this before is set overflow to hidden and put the full string to a alt text so you can see it if you hover. I dont know if thats what your going for but its something i  use sometimes.

If not that try looking at useing jquery ui hide effects thats a good looking way to do it. Hope that helps

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the ideas. The alt text won't work for this particular situation. Regarding jquery, I wasn't able to come up with a solution. I want the table and its cells to stretch/shrink with the browser resize like it would normally, but I want one of the cells to have content that overflows when the table overflows so that the table doesn't overflow. I'm sure it can be done with jquery/javascript, but not without a complicated script. Would you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Why not give the div a max width of 100% and place it around the entire table?

http://jsfiddle.net/wJUyL/

```
<div style="max-width:100%; overflow:auto;">
    <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td>
ReallyLongUnbrokenStringOfCharactersThatStretchesTheTableBeyondItsContainerReallyLongUnbrokenStringOfCharactersThatStretchesTheTableBeyondItsContainerReallyLongUnbrokenStringOfCharactersThatStretchesTheTableBeyondItsContainer
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this. I'm not a fan of the look of it... scrolling the entire table versus just the offending table cell. Plus the table can potentially be large, putting the horizontal scrollbar all the way at the bottom of the page.